# Writing to internal SD card on Android

Tags: android, special-folders, android-sdcard

Is there any way of accessing the internal SD card on Android devices that have internal flash, internal SD and external SD cards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android 2.2 and previous, there is only one "external storage" (`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`). The definition of where this points is up to the device manufacturer. The Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) merely mandates that it be at least 2GB, IIRC. It is not even required for "external storage" to be removable.

At this time, there are no standard APIs to get to other partitions or cards. A device manufacturer might document how to access these -- you would have to see if they have anything on their respective developer sites.

Bear in mind that on some of these devices, other partitions or cards may not be readable or writable from regular SDK applications.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I feared. I've posed the question to the device manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not there in your memory card/sd card. There is non-writing setting enable in default mobile setting.

- First, navigate to */system/etc/permissions/platform.xml*
- After the location been located, make the coding as:

  ```
  <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
      <group gid="sdcard_r"/>
      <group gid="sdcard_rw"/>
      <group gid="media_rw"/>
  </permission>
  ```

  and on the other part of the coding make changes as:

  ```
  <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE">
      <group gid="sdcard_rw"/>
      <group gid="media_rw"/>
  </permission>
  ```

Comment: Could you summarize the steps from the video? If the video ever is removed or the URL changes, then it will be useless (or would require updating this post)...

Comment: First navigate to     /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml

Comment: After the location been located.    Make the coding as <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"><group gid="sdcard_r"/><group gid="sdcard_rw"/><group gid="media_rw"/></permission>       and on the other part of the coding make changes as  <permission name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"><group gid="sdcard_rw"/><group gid="media_rw"/></permission>

Comment: I have added the context to your post. In the future, please add updates to the post instead of adding them in comment