# Find the location of android device's Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way using ADB to know the location of what a specific plugged in device will return for Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ?

I would like to push a file there and then read this file from the activity running on the device. I think this path can vary based on device, and I will have to run this on numerous different android devices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now you could probably get away with just using "/sdcard" in case you don't find a better solution.
It's defined pretty static in the [Android source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/os/Environment.java#l92).

Comment: I guess based on the answer to this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591494/writing-to-internal-sd-card-on-android

I am worried the manufacturer may have changed it. Is that super unlikely?

Comment: It may happen but i don't see a reason for them to change it as long as they use only one sdcard. Since the path is buried in the Android source and not in some config file i would say its unlikely.

Comment: tried a few diff devices Samsung/LG/Huwaie) and this seemed to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

is 'adb shell "echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE"' what you have been looking for?